# What should be the 1.e4 and 1.d4 tag info

Tags: discussion

[1.e4](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1.e4) tag has a tag info as follows:

> 1. e4 is White's most common first move (except at the top grandmaster level). It tends to produce open games.

Do we have any sources that shows "except at the top grandmaster level" part? I think this definition is a bit vague as what a "top grandmaster" means is not clear. I thought e4 is also the most popular move at the highest level.

[1.d4](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1.d4) tag has a tag info as follows:

> 1. d4 is one of White's two most common first moves. It tends to produce closed games.

Moreover, both tags have an ending as "it tends to produce open/closed games". I disagree with this part too. There are high number of openings with `1.e4` which produce close games, and similarly, there are high number of openings with `1.d4` which produce open games.

I didn't send an edit request directly as I am also not sure what they should be, hence I am asking here. I believe they are wrong as they are right now.